# CSS to add image to text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment, I have page headings which I want to style like this:

```
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
```

My style looks like this:

```
.page_header {
    font-family: markerfelt-thin-webfont;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #bbbb75;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

But I have been asked to add a small image to the left of the text.

So, I could go an edit every page header:

```
<div class="page_header"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/e/S/a/V/m/push-pin-th.png" />Categories</div>
```

But I was hoping I could edit the CSS to accomplish this for me. Is there a way I can add an image to the CSS, left of the text (With a (missing) gap between the image and the text)?

I have attempted the ::before in the css (New to me, so I am doing something wrong), like this:

```
.page_header {

    font-family: markerfelt-thin-webfont;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #bbbb75;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.page_header::before{
    content: url('~/images/pushpin.png');
}
```

But all that happens is I get a huge gap before the heading. But if I use http:// to reference the image, it works. Using ~\images\myimage.png fails.

Comment: Can you provide a sample image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: English error. I was hoping it's possible to do it with CSS. Yes, I can modify the CSS.

Comment: Edited with sample image.

Comment: @Craig i would use :before  https://jsbin.com/vunowovavi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: there are lot of way to do something like. you can simple set image in backgroud and give position-size as per your requirement , you can :before and append image there and give styling to :before as per requirement

Comment: I tried the 'before' thing, but, edited my question with my attempt and failed result.

Comment: @Craig do you have a fiddle? Did you check my Jsbin?

Comment: @Craig try replacing your relative path with an absolute URL.

Comment: Works if I use the absolute URL. Is there no way to use the relative path?

Comment: @Craig I'm making a lot of assumptions about your setup but,  I think you can use relative URLs based on Apache's document root.

Comment: Sorry, my setup is a .Net application on Azure, using Bootstrap as the UI. As soon as I replace the http://myhost.com/image/myimage.png with ~/images/myimage.png - the image dissapears from the page, and is replaced with a large empty block. I can't use jsfiddle because I need to demonstrate the issue with a local file.

Comment: Removing the ~ works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try with code below maybe can help you:

```
.page_header {

    font-family: markerfelt-thin-webfont;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #bbbb75;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position:relative;
    padding: 30px 0 0 120px;
}
.page_header::before{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    content:url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/e/S/a/V/m/push-pin-th.png');
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/gas0a94m/)

Comment: I am trying this, and it works if I use 'http://' to point to my image. I need to use ~/image/myimage.png instead though, and when I use that, it fails.

Comment: Removing the '~' has fixed the issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can style all headers with the same image:

```css
.page_header {
    background: url('http://www.healthylivingjunkie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bulletPoints.png') left center no-repeat;
    background-size: 14px;
    font-family: markerfelt-thin-webfont;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #bbbb75;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to achieve this. Either by use of the [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) selector or by setting the background of the div to your image and pushing the text across using padding.

Comment: Tried that. I edited my question with my attempt. Didn't work. Can you spot an issue?

Comment: Ah, but using http in the content works. Can I not use a file in my project? ~\images\image.png for example?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background image of the div and pad the left side to move the text over

```
padding-left:120px; // width of image + spacing
background: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/e/S/a/V/m/push-pin-th.png") no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you don't have to go to code part and you can do this with css using **pseudo element** `before` as you have to insert it before the element.

```css
.page_header:before{
    content:url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/e/S/a/V/m/push-pin-th.png'); 
}
```

```html
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
<div class="page_header">Categories</div>
```