# Putting common image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the bullet, shown on right side in image below, inside a CSS class so that I mention the style in the row and need not insert the image every time. As the images keeps on changing with new themes, I want to put in CSS.

[image]

> It needs to be in the row of the table individually and cant be in list.

My CSS is as follows, but it doesn't work

```
.ABP2_Bullet {
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
src: url("../../../../CBTShared.edu/CBTShared.doc/src/images/CATBulletBlue3_IF_WE.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Another option I tried is

```
.bullet_IfWe{
list-style-image:url(../images/CATBulletBlue3_IF_WE.png);
list-style-position:inherit;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is almost correct, instead of `src` you want `background`. Also, you may want to set it to inline-block if you are using a span.

```
.ABP2_Bullet {
    display: inline;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background: url("../../../../CBTShared.edu/CBTShared.doc/src/images/CATBulletBlue3_IF_WE.png") no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Usage:

```
<span class="ABP2_Bullet"></span>
```

Here's a similar question that just got asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31332064/584192

Comment: Got it @Samuel, your link to similar question was useful too.

Answer (score 5):

The `src` attribute of an image is not a CSS property, and cannot be styled. The `list-style-image` property can only be used to style the images used for each item in a bulleted list (e.g, `ol` / `li`), not for other elements*.

You can get a *similar* effect to what you're describing by setting a `background-image` on a non-image element with `background-repeat: none` and an appropriate `background-position`. Details will depend on the surrounding HTML.

---

*: Technically it's possible to turn any element into a bulleted list using `display: list-item`, but it's generally not advisable.

Comment: never tried to style 'src' by the way. May be i confused you. Objective was to get rid of the img src everytime and replace it with the style.

Comment: Your first example is trying to do exactly that: `src: url("…")` on the fourth line.

Comment: Oh I see, yes, got it .